# Outlook .MSG file contains to many recipients then To property gets blank return null

Tags: c#, .net, outlook

When trying to read the **.msg** file in .Net using the dll `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook` Version 15.0.0.0 facing the issue in reading large recipients.

Scenarios:

1. If the .msg file contains less recipients e.g less than 300 then value in `To` property shows actual recipients.
2. If the .msg file has more than 300 recipients then `To` property of `MailItem` object is getting `null` shows no blank.

Does the library have any limitations for the recipients to read or anything I am missing to handle more recipients?

```
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

    var item = app.Session.OpenSharedItem(msgfilepath) as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem;
    string message = item.Body
    string recipients = item.To   
   //This To property gets null in case file has large recipients list.
```

Comment: Try looping over the Recipients collection:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28986306/get-item-recipient-with-outlook-vba

Comment: @TimWilliams. Yes try with Recipients property and getting the collection of recipients but my actual problem is not getting it in `To` property for large recipients only,

Comment: If the number of recipients is large then you *need* to loop over the Recipients collection.  That's just how it is, and it works fine: if you only want the "To" items, look at each recipient's `Type` property.

Comment: Why is this question tagged vba or outlook-vba?

Comment: Good call @BrakNicku. The code provided is C#. I changed the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
string recipients = item.To
```

To this:

```
string recipients = string.Join(";", item.Recipients);
```

The result will be an identical semi-colon delimited string but the second one will always work.

The official documentation doesn't talk about a limit on the .To property but it does tell you to use Recipients:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._mailitem.to